# how to change card background color in bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

i want to change the background color of a card in bootstrap from the normal color or ***"bg-primary"*** to ***rgba*** color of my choice.

```
card {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
 }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all - you used `card` instead of `.card` selector. If you want to set your own `background-color` for `.card` you should remove `.bg-primary` class and set rules for `.card`:

```
.card {
    ...
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    ...
}
```

Second - in bootrstrap 4 `background-color` of `.bg-primary` is declared with `!important`, so it overrides any other declarations:

```
.bg-primary {
    background-color: #007bff!important;
}
```

You can either add your own class to `.card`:

```
.bg-custom-1 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Or you can set your color for `.bg-primary` if you still want to use it (make sure that your css goes after bootstrap css):

```
.bg-primary {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)!important;
}
```

Comment: i tried the first one and it didn't work even tho i didn't use bg-primary it can't be changed this way i don't know why it works fine when using card:hover but doesn't work on .card, thx anyway for your time :)